# What is the economic nature of water?

Tags: definition, resource-economics

How should one classify water in economic terms?

Is it a commodity, a natural resource, can it be both? Does it depend on how it is being used (e.g., as input/raw material in some process)? I was curious about all the ways water could be characterized economically (e.g., as a rival good, a commodity etc.) and would be grateful for some pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the terms you mention are not mutually exclusive.

Commodity is not a specialized term and it just denotes some (mostly) fungible economic good (see [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commodity) or [here](https://www.economist.com/the-economist-explains/2017/01/03/what-makes-something-a-commodity)). So water is a commodity.

Natural resources can be defined as ([OECD 2005](https://stats.oecd.org/glossary/detail.asp?ID=1740#:%7E:text=Definition%3A,for%20economic%20production%20or%20consumption.)):

> Natural resources are natural assets (raw materials) occurring in nature that can be used for economic production or consumption.

So water is also a natural resource.

In terms of economic classification water (tap or bottled) is *private good* because it is both rival and excludable (see Mankiw Principles of Economics pp 226). However, here it also depends which water we are talking about. I assume you mean tap or bottled drinking water. An argument could be that water in rivers, lakes and seas is non-excludable (in the case of lakes it would also depend on size of the lake). If we would be talking about water in a sea it would *common resource* because of non-excludability.

Comment: +1  I would just add that while clean fresh water  is clearly both a commodity and a natural resource, it would be difficult to argue that salt water is a commodity if commanding a price is part of the definition of a commodity.  There is just too much in the oceans for there to be any issue of scarcity giving rise to a price.  On the other hand salt water is a natural resource, eg as an input to desalination plants producing fresh water, and for use as a coolant in coastal nuclear power stations.

Comment: +1 I also would like to add that it falls under "land" in LLK: Land, Labor, (K)Capital.